# How to Replace data in SQLite Table - Android C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, mysql, sqlite, xamarin

I am trying to make it so I can Edit data in the SQLite Table, but it is giving me and error. What I want to do is to Click the Edit button and have the data already displayed in the ListView be edited with a new string from an Alert Dialog.

Update / Edit Code:

```
public void UpdateNote(String note)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.WritableDatabase;
    db.Replace(DB_TABLE, DB_COLUMN + " = ?", new String[] { note });
    db.Close();
}
```

This will be called from an Alert Dialog Positive Button.

The error I am receiving:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGDxV.png)

**UPDATE 1:**

Custom Adapter:

```
 btnEdit.Click += delegate
            {

                string noteOld = noteList[position];

                mainActivity.UpdateNote(noteOld);
                //reload data
                mainActivity.LoadNoteList();
            };
```

Above Calls MainActivity:

```
public void UpdateNote(String noteOld)
        {
            string oldNote = noteOld;
            noteEditText = new EditText(this);
            noteEditText.Text = oldNote;
            noteEditText.SetLines(5);
            noteEditText.SetTextColor(Color.Black);
            noteEditText.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
            noteEditText.SetMaxLines(5);
            //noteEditText.SetGravity(Gravity.Top);
            alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.SetTitle("Edit Note");
            alert.SetMessage("");
            alert.SetView(noteEditText);
            alert.SetPositiveButton("Save", UpdateOkAction);
            alert.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", CancelAction);
            alert.Create();
            alert.Show();

        }
```

Which Calls MainActivity method:

```
 public void UpdateOkAction(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
        {
            string noteNew = noteEditText.Text;
            dbHelper.UpdateNote(oldNote);
            LoadNoteList();
        }
```

Which then goes to DbHelper.cs:

```
public void UpdateNote(String noteNew)
        {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.WritableDatabase;
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.Put("Note", noteNew); // Column name and value respectively
            db.Update(DB_TABLE, values, DB_COLUMN + " = ?", new String[] { noteNew });
        }
```

I cannot parse the noteNew and oldNote both to the DbHelper to replace the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void UpdateNote(String note)
{    
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.WritableDatabase;

    dataToInsert.put(YOUR_COLUMN_NAME_HERE, note); // Column name and value respectively


    String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id)};

    db.update(DB_TABLE, dataToInsert, "id=?", whereArgs);
}
```

Comment: It is giving an Error saying `whereArgs does not exist in the current context`

Comment: you should change the part i comment to fit your database and data. replace `"note","note"` with your info.

Comment: It is Updating the data, but only by a set `String`, how would I make it so the string is coming from a user input `Alert Dialog`? Keep in mind that the code above is in `DBHelper.cs`

Comment: I edit my answer. just replace the field name that you wanna update with `YOUR_COLUMN_NAME_HERE`.

Comment: How would i get the `String note` from MainActivity?

Comment: I don't know! because you only send your `UpdateNote` function here.

Comment: I am not quite familiar with this area but i guess you should use an `intent` and get `noteNew` with `Bundle`.

Comment: It turns old I had to declare a `public static string oldNote;` inside the Class, and it works now! But your code helped alot! Thank you! Will upvote and Mark